# Python Tkinter: How to create_line with multiple points in a list/tuple?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

There is a list of coordinates that I want to draw lines through on the Tkinter canvas:

```
points = [(1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (2, 0)]   # etc. This is could have 100 points or more
```

The next step would be calling the function create_line, but it can't support list:

```
Canvas.create_line(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)       #this works ok
Canvas.create_line(points)                 #this doesn't work
```

So is there an efficient way to separate the elements in a list and insert them into the function in this order? If possible, I would love to avoid using for loops.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the list `points` with a list comprehension:

```
flattened = [a for x in points for a in x]
```

And turn the elements of that flattened list into arguments with the "*" syntax:

```
Canvas.create_line(*flattened)
```

I politely suggest that you overcome your hangup about for loops.  It is pretty much impossible to write useful programs without them.